# In genealogy, what is the plural of proof?

Tags: grammatical-number

In genealogy, a birth certificate, a marriage license, and a census record are each examples of a proof.

If I am going to say, "Send your application with all genealogical proofs..." is that correct?

Some people use the word proof for both singular and plural.
I favor proof for singular and proofs for plural.
Which is correct? Or are both correct

Comment: I think the relevant question isn't what the plural form is but whether it's a count noun.